# Where is the old EBP and return address?

Tags: c, x86, return, cpu-registers

I'm having some trouble understanding where to find the EBP and return addresses.  From my understanding, a call to sub is made to reserve space for the local variables within a function.  I'm a bit confused on this code in particular..

```
void countLines(FILE* f){
char buf[0x400];//should be big enough for anybody
int lines=0;
fread(buf,READSIZE,1,f);  

for(int i=0;i<0x400;i++)
  if(buf[i] == '\n')
    lines++;


printf("The number of lines in the file is %d\n",lines);
return;
}
```

After disassembling this function with gdb, I get:

```
0x08048484 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048485 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048487 <+3>:    sub    $0x428,%esp
```

Why 0x428?  Adding up the local variable lengths, I only get 0x408 (char[400], lines, and i).  Furthermore, are the EBP and return address found immediately following the reserved space?

Comment: `push   %ebp` next instruction pointer, `$0x428, %esp` adding because `esp` is base address of `buf`

Comment: instead do more thing compare it with asm generated by `gcc -S` (in that file you will get probably more semantic informations)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan So what you're saying is that `esp` is where the first byte of `buf` is found and `esp` - 0x400 is where the last byte of it is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the function prologue has executed, your stack looks like this:

```
*****
*****
return address
old EBP   <---- EBP
.....
..F..
..r..
..e..          (0x428 bytes)
..e..
.....      <---  ESP
```

To return from the function, you simply restore ESP to the value held in EBP, pop the previous EBP back from the stack, and call `ret`. This in turn will pop the return address off the stack and jump there:

```
mov %ebp, %esp
pop %ebp
ret
```

(The point of keeping EBP around is so that you don't have to remember the how much you've incremented ESP during your function (think `alloca`). You don't *have* to use EBP, though, e.g. with GCC's `-fomit-frame-pointer`.)

Comment: Ok, I believe this answered what I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Function args (and probably registers) are also saved in that 0x428-byte space. Also, when calling other functions, instead of using `push`/`pop`, GCC will simply store args relative to `esp` (for example, `mov 0x4(%esp),%eax`).

So 0x428 comes from 0x408 (local vars) + 0x4 (arguments) + 0x10 (space for up to 4 arguments for `fread`) + 0x8 (probably something else I'm missing, possibly registers).